# What could cause a Raspberry pi 4, running Retropie, to shut down in the middle of gameplay?

Tags: pi-4

I have it hooked up to a four player joystick system hooked up to 1 joystick, and 7 buttons per controller setup(ordered from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KFBZ32H)). I am currently overclocking to 2ghz, using a cano 5.2 v 3.5a power supply.

Comment: Probably the overclock, try reducing it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try that out.

Comment: If you have lost your original login credentials see ["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) or else ask the question again **and keep your password this time**.